# How to do google authentication for web api ASP.NET Framework without ASP.NET identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I created a Web API .NET framework project from scratch without authentication. And I already have my local SQL database where I created controllers to access some of that data.

Now I decided to include Google authentication.

I created a new table called `Users` that has columns like First Name, Last Name, Email and Phone number. Do I need to add other columns, or are there other tables I need to create?

And what to do to be able to login using Google?

Comment: Where will the user click the "Sign in with Google"? Is there another app for that? In which platform?

Comment: No. You don't need Identity for Google Authentication. You can store user info anywhere you like